# How to monitor user click on an url and extract the url?

Tags: android, url, extract, monitor

I'm doing a project which can detect phishing website. I.e. when a user tap on a link when they browsing a webpage in a browser, the link will be check if it is a phishing webpage.

However, I do not know how to recognize that if the user is clicking a url when they perform a tap action.

Also, even if a click on a url can be recognized, how to extract the url in string form so that i can check the link ?

It seems that there is no API of the browser available for me to use.

Answer (score 1):

There is an API. Use an IntentFilter. Here is an example. Note that the data field is optional:

```
<activity
        android:name="MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <data
                android:host="127.0.0.1"
                android:path="/path"
                android:port="18080"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

To get the Uri use this snippet in your Activity:

```
Intent intent = MyActivity.this.getIntent();
Uri uri = intent.getData();
```

Comment: I forgot you can register your application for certain events. This is only viable if the user selects this application as the default, or if they pick it from the list though

Comment: @Mimminito that's true, but this is actually still a viable solution. You could simply have your app "forward" the intent if it's a good URL or display a warning if it's detected as a phishing URL and then let the user continue on anyway or exit. There's no other way around it anyway assuming you want to catch it *before* the URL is loaded (though that may not be 100% required, it would certainly seem better).

Comment: Yes, it is a viable option, and the best I can see right now.

Answer (score 1):

You CAN hook into the default Browser application. Some browser data is available through the content provider. The following code will get you a list of URLs the user has visited :

```
String columns[] = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE, Browser.BookmarkColumns._ID };
Cursor c = managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, columns, "bookmark!=1", null, null);
```

You can place a ContentObserver on the browser history to be notified when a user has visited a new page. In this way, you *should* be alerted even if the user has installed a non standard browser.

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, true, new MyContentObserver(handler));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hook into the default Browser application. You will need to write your own WebBrowser application which will allow you to intercept the taps on a webpage.